# Не работает Fancybox на некоторых страницах сайта (Битрикс)

Tags: javascript, jquery, битрикс, fancybox

На сайте установлен js Fancybox для просмотра изображений. Везде работает, кроме одной группы страниц. В чем может быть причина? Подключен он везде в шаблоне. Не могу понять в чем причина и даже в какую сторону смотреть

Comment: в консоли ошибки есть?

Comment: нет, никаких ошибок не выдает. Просто на части страниц показывает изображения как надо, а на части просто открывает в окне без применения Fancybox. Очень извиняюсь, что не могу дать более адекватной информации

Comment: Пиши подробности хоть какие-нибудь. В чем особенность этой группы страниц, после чего началось, используется ли ajax-подгрузка контента в шаблоне, приводи пример кода в конце концов, что угодно, а то экстрасенсов тут очень мало

Comment: режим ajax в настройках шаблона компонента отключен. Показывается на страницах каталога и не показывается на страницах "Статьи". Отвалилось после верстки когда-то давно, но сразу не заметили. Код бы я привела,но даже не знаю какую часть кода показать,чтобы прояснить ситуацию.

Comment: Предполагаю, что проблема в шаблоне компонента. Может есть конкретные строки необходимые для работы фэнсибокса?

Comment: судя по шаблону тех страниц, где он отвалился, там нигде не отсылает к Fancybox

Comment: Ну конечно есть конкретные строки, в каком-то месте он должен запускаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за отклики, стимулирующих мозговой процесс ) Вспомнила все, что происходило с этими страницами и оказалось, что проблема решается просто! При переверстке этого компонента указали другой класс. Нужно просто найти эту строку в шаблоне компонента и переименовать класс